# scrollIntoView not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have the following problem.

I have a tree view control in .NET and I have created a autocomplete search box to search the tree for a name - which then I can select and it highlights the item with a selected class.

The tree view is pretty long so I have given it a height and overflow scroll.

The problem is that I want view or scroll down to the selected item when I've searched for it.

So i have created the following script to scrollIntoView it but this doesn't seem to work:

```
function search_itemSelected(sender, e) {
        var hdSearchID = $get('<%= hdSearchID.ClientID %>');
        hdSearchID.value = e.get_value();
        var selectedElement = $("div.node.cen.selected"); // This works
        if (selectedElement != null) {
            selectedElement[0].scrollIntoView = 10; // This keeps coming back as undefined
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First:** change

```
if (selectedElement != null)
```

to

```
if (selectedElement.length)
```

because `$("div.node.cen.selected");` will never return `null`. jQuery always returns a jQuery object (*empty or not, but a jQuery object*)

So in the case where it is empty, the `selectedElement[0]` will return undefined and thus the `scrollIntoView` does not exist..

**Second:** [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) is a function and so you do not assign a value to it. You need to call it with

```
selectedElement[0].scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 2):

`scrollIntoView` is used with element you want to show, like that :

```
el.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Note:

Scrolls the window until the element is visible.

Syntax:

document.all.elementID.scrollIntoView(param1)

Parameters:
    param1   Optional; true or false, indicating whether the top of the element 
                       is scrolled to the top of the window or the bottom of the 
                       element is scrolled to the bottom of the window.

**Moreover, `scrollIntoView()` can only be used with some tags**

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Methods/scrollIntoViewisappliedto.htm